# implementing custom list.addAll()

Tags: grails, collections, groovy

I am using groovy/grails, and I have a ResultList in my service which I am using to store query results. 
The list contains Objects of each months transactions like txn_jan, txn_feb ...txn_dec. 
 
So list contents are as follows:

```
def qresultList = [txn_jan1,txn_jan2,txn_feb1,txn_april1,txn_dec1]
```

Each of these is an object that contains fields location and transaction count (tcount).

I want to iterate the list to get a list of distinct locations and their summed up transaction count. So something similar to the pseudo code below:
`if txn_jan1.location = txn_feb1.location then the output list should contain txn_jan1.location and count= txn_jan1.tcount + txn_feb1.tcount.`
finally in the result list I need to have a list of distinct locations and their updated counts.
How do I write this in groovy?
Regards,
Priyank

Comment: An example of the list for us to work with would really help... The description is a bit vague

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to use [`groupBy`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#groupBy%28groovy.lang.Closure%29) to group by location.  Then you can collect over the groups to get the sum of transactions.  For example:

```
def qresultList = [
    [location: 'a', txs: 10],
    [location: 'b', txs: 20],
    [location: 'a', txs: 30]
]

def totalsByLocation1 = qresultList.groupBy{ it.location }.
    collectEntries{ key, vals -> [key, vals*.txs.sum()] }

assert totalsByLocation1 == ['a': 40, 'b': 20]
```

An alternative is to just iterate over the list and accumulate the total transactions in map:

```
def totalsByLocation2 = [:].withDefault{0}

qresultList.each { totalsByLocation2[it.location] += it.txs }

assert totalsByLocation2 == ['a': 40, 'b': 20]
```

Comment: just one final thing remaining is ..how to name the first field as location and count as t_count so I can access them as it.location and it.t_count so the final list should be [location: 'a', txs: 40..] instead of ['a':40]

Comment: `collectEntries` results in a map.  To get a list of maps, use `collect`: `qresultList.groupBy{ it.location }.
    collect{ key, vals -> [location: key, t_count: vals*.txs.sum()] }`